# What AC1200 or faster wifi add-in cards work out-of-the-box with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, hardware

Yes, I've seen [this list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) and it is horribly out of date. Many/some of the entries were last updated in 2007. I'm looking for AC1200 at least, preferably higher standard add in cards for desktop computers, *not laptops*. Yes, I have an ancient blue Trendnet USB dongle that works with anything, it is also slow. I put in a Gigabit network and want to take advantage off it when accessing my on-network storage. I can't string cables everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Given the deafening silence on here I had to do some trial and error experimentation that lead to this blog post.

https://www.logikalsolutions.com/wordpress/information-technology/ubuntu-20-04-lts-compatible-wifi-card/

A generic Intel AC 3165 seems to work with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS out of the box.

I have since learned the cable is to plug into a USB connection port on the motherboard. It's really sad since they use way less than half of the pins that you have to give up an entire mobo USB port.

**You do not have to use the cable.**

That is for the Bluetooth on the card.

I found the card on eBay for under $20